# gettext po file editor to show multiple po files

Tags: translation, gettext, po

In our company we are trying to decide whether to use english for our message id or whether we should invent some kind of key. We can only take the second approach if there are editors which allow us to work on multiple po files in one interface because translators will need to use english in order to translate into another language rather than translating from some cryptic message id.

Is there a tool which basically circumvents the messageid and allows translation from one language into another?

Answer (score 1):

I guess many translation tools do support this mode as it is used by several translation formats (like Android resource strings or Java properties). However it is not commonly used with Gettext (as you might easily end up with application showing message ID instead of not translated text).

I believe it should work with [Weblate](http://weblate.org/), though most likely nobody has ever used this mode with Gettext files.

Update: This mode is fully supported in Weblate and used by many projects now.